# How to choose between `HSET users my_user 1234` and `SET users:my_user 1234`

Tags: redis

I would like to retrieve the id associated to a user and I see two ways of doing it in Redis. I am wondering which way is the most efficient (or the best in term of best practice) for doing this task

1) `HSET users my_user 1234`

Whish I would retrieve using:
`HGET users my_user`

2) `SET users:my_user 1234`

Which I would retrieve using:
`GET users:my_user`

I saw in a database I was working on, things like:

`SET index_1:index_2:index_3:index_4 1234`

Is that the correct way of indexing a value ?

Comment: 1 creates a hash and 2 creates a simple key. It depends on the use case, a key might be enough for a simple key value binding, while a hash can take more information about your my_user, but might be overkill for a simple key value binding

Comment: I agree with @baao comment. Just to complete that you can use also MSET in order to set multiple key values in an atomic way.